# Unexpected complication data (Galaxy Watch 4)

Tags: java, android, wear-os, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy-watch

I've created simple complication which shows air pressure in hhmg units (because default one uses hPa units).

It works perfectly on Pixel Watch.

But when I've installed it on Galaxy Watch 4 it doesn't appear in the list of complications.

The only thing I've noticed, this log message:

```
WCS com.google.android.wearable.app W  [PackageChecker]Unexpected complication data type RANGED_TEXT
```

This is my manifest entry:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".C"
    android:exported="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sun_not"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="com.google.android.wearable.permission.BIND_COMPLICATION_PROVIDER">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.support.wearable.complications.ACTION_COMPLICATION_UPDATE_REQUEST"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.wearable.complications.SUPPORTED_TYPES"
        android:value="RANGED_TEXT" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.wearable.complications.UPDATE_PERIOD_SECONDS"
        android:value="3600" />
</service>
```

And there is the code:

```java
public class C extends ComplicationDataSourceService {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ComplicationData getPreviewData(@NonNull ComplicationType complicationType) {
        return data(750);
    }

    private RangedValueComplicationData data(float value) {
        final PlainComplicationText d = new PlainComplicationText.Builder("ммрс").build();
        final Icon icon = Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_sun_not);
        final String str = String.valueOf(Math.round(value));
        final PlainComplicationText text = new PlainComplicationText.Builder(str).build();
        return new RangedValueComplicationData
            .Builder(value, 720, 780, d)
            .setMonochromaticImage(new MonochromaticImage.Builder(icon).build())
            .setTitle(text)
            .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplicationRequest(
            @NonNull ComplicationRequest complicationRequest,
            @NonNull ComplicationRequestListener complicationRequestListener
    ) {
        final L l = new L();
        final SensorManager sensMan = getSystemService(SensorManager.class);
        final Sensor sensor = sensMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);
        sensMan.registerListener(l, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final float hhmg = l.lastValue * HPA_TO_MMHG;
                try {
                    complicationRequestListener.onComplicationData(data(hhmg));
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                sensMan.unregisterListener(l);
            }
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

And (just in case it's relevant) dependency in build.gradle:

```
implementation("androidx.wear.watchface:watchface-complications-data-source:1.1.1")
```